# Tailwind scroll to bottom on page load or new line

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

This is a chat app I am building. What is SUPPOSED to happen with the CSS is the div should always show the latest message at the bottom. When someone types a new message, it should scroll down to the bottom to show the newest message. Right now all it does is post the new message but doesnt scroll and on page reload the oldest message is shown at the top not the newest at the bottom (you gotta scroll to see it.

```
<div class="h-full pb-2 mb-2 pt-0 mt-0 shadow-md overflow-y-auto">
  <div class="flex flex-col-reverse justify-end">
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div>
        <div class="flex space-x-3 px-3">
          <img class="mt-4 h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="http://localhost:8000/storage/profile-photos/GGsymBqzbfC6nOWHyFsBEwAdqJtICgo0DcypPlMR.jpg" alt="Ryan Olson">
          <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
              <h3 class="pt-2 text-sm font-medium">Ryan Olson</h3>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">9/2/2021, 12:12:49 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="text-md text-gray-500">this is a test</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-gray-100">
      <div>
        <div class="flex space-x-3 px-3">
          <img class="mt-4 h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="http://localhost:8000/storage/profile-photos/GGsymBqzbfC6nOWHyFsBEwAdqJtICgo0DcypPlMR.jpg" alt="Ryan Olson">
          <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
              <h3 class="pt-2 text-sm font-medium">Ryan Olson</h3>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">9/2/2021, 12:09:34 PM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="text-md text-gray-500">testing</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div>
        <div class="flex space-x-3 px-3">
          <img class="mt-4 h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="http://localhost:8000/storage/profile-photos/GGsymBqzbfC6nOWHyFsBEwAdqJtICgo0DcypPlMR.jpg" alt="Ryan Olson">
          <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
              <h3 class="pt-2 text-sm font-medium">Ryan Olson</h3>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">9/1/2021, 12:46:38 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="text-md text-gray-500">fhfdgh</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-gray-100">
      <div>
        <div class="flex space-x-3 px-3">
          <img class="mt-4 h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="http://localhost:8000/storage/profile-photos/GGsymBqzbfC6nOWHyFsBEwAdqJtICgo0DcypPlMR.jpg" alt="Ryan Olson">
          <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
              <h3 class="pt-2 text-sm font-medium">Ryan Olson</h3>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">9/1/2021, 12:45:38 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="text-md text-gray-500">https://localhost:8000</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div>
        <div class="flex space-x-3 px-3">
          <img class="mt-4 h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="http://localhost:8000/storage/profile-photos/GGsymBqzbfC6nOWHyFsBEwAdqJtICgo0DcypPlMR.jpg" alt="Ryan Olson">
          <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
              <h3 class="pt-2 text-sm font-medium">Ryan Olson</h3>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">9/1/2021, 12:39:47 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="text-md text-gray-500">How much does it tap into the web server</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-gray-100">
      <div>
        <div class="flex space-x-3 px-3">
          <img class="mt-4 h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="http://localhost:8000/storage/profile-photos/GGsymBqzbfC6nOWHyFsBEwAdqJtICgo0DcypPlMR.jpg" alt="Ryan Olson">
          <div class="flex-1 space-y-1">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
              <h3 class="pt-2 text-sm font-medium">Ryan Olson</h3>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">9/1/2021, 12:39:34 AM</p>
            </div>
            <p class="text-md text-gray-500">I wonder how this works</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am just not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside `<div class="flex flex-col-reverse justify-end">` I had to also put `h-full`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me : [CodePen here](https://codepen.io/Eli0uz/pen/MWqxwgX)